# FFmpeg video trimming without acodec is time-consuming

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using yt-dlp to get a direct link to the video. Some 360p and 720p links have an acodec. yt-dlp formats

In case if you trim a video with a segment of 5 minutes for example, a video that has acodec will be trimmed in seconds, while the same segment in the same quality but without acodec will take several minutes.

The FFmpeg command I use:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:05:00 -i "direct_video_link" -c copy video.mp4`

With the `-c copy` argument, trimming video with an acodec takes less time but does not affect the speed of video without an acodec.

The yt-dlp command I use:

video with acodec - `yt-dlp -S res:720,acodec:mp4a.40.2,ext:mp4,proto:https,fps30 -g "link"`

video without acodec - `yt-dlp -S res:720,ext:mp4,proto:https,fps30 -g "link"`